# Teminal Beeps with rinruby

Tags: ruby, r, macos, terminal

I am using the snippet of code bellow for calling some R code from Ruby. I have been making calculations and it seems to work fine but when I run it in OS X Terminal I am hearing a beep for each R line. There is any way to avoid getting the beeps? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
require 'rinruby'

r = RinRuby.new(:echo => false)
r.x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
r.y = [0, 0, 0.129, 0, 0.129, 0.13, 0.261, 0.131, 0.131, 0.263, 0, 0.398]
r.eval <<EOF
    lm1 <- lm(y ~ x)
    slope = lm1$coefficients[2]
EOF

p r.pull("slope")
```

Comment: Do you still get the beeps if you run `ruby my_script.rb | tr -d "\a"`?